# Apache redirects www.domain.com to domain.com/domain

Tags: redirect, web, apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm preparing my ubuntu server in Amazon AWS to host a new website. It uses Apache2. I've done this before with no problem whatsoever, for example, to trick a friend I spoofed google.com and www.google.com (editing his hosts file) and everything worked fine with and without 'www.'.

Now I have bought a domain name 'domain.com' with 1&1 , I have configured a subdomain 'www.domain.com' and I have pointed it to my server. The dns record is fine, I checked. I have also edited my sites-enabled default file and added these entries:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit domain.com in my browser it works fine, but when I visit www.domain.com I get **domain.com/domain/** and obviously a 404.

I used telnet and discovered that the server sends a 301 when you request the root page of host: www.domain.com

I don't know why this is happening, I've tried lots of modifications to the configuration above like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName domain.com
    Server Alias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

but it kept happening.

For the record, this is what I used for the spoof that still works fine

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName google.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/google
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName www.google.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/google
</VirtualHost>
```

I've been searching for two days now, but all I find is the same configuration I'm using and no explanation about why this isn't working.

Thanks for your help!

PS: There are no .htaccess files in this directory or in any of the parent directories.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody enters this question.

I still don't know what was wrong but after moving these configurations around the file they've magically started working normally.

Thanks to everybody who took the time to read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to put

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

You can't put a space between Server and Alias so I changed to show you

Hope It Works!